# ArcGIS Pro Pop-up not displaying or updating attributes

Tags: arcgis-pro, popup

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.1 on Windows 10 Enterprise and there seems to be persistent issues when viewing feature attributes within the 'Pop-up' which is accessed via the 'Explore' tool on the Map toolbar  Issues include:

1. Pop-up box is empty no attributes are displayed. They only become visible if the pop-up box is resized (see image below)
2. The vertical scroll bar seems to be disabled, and when they are visible they don't seem to slide up or down.
3. When I do resize the pop-up box and can see the attributes they don't update when I click on a new feature.

Anyone else experienced this and able share how they have resolved it, or is software bug?

[image: Screenshot of pop-up]

[I have looked at this ESRI Technical Support '*Pop-ups do not display the attribute information in ArcGIS Pro*' but this is not the same issue](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000025018)

[Note I have looked at this short YouTube video '*ArcGIS Pro Pop-ups not displaying*' however this is not the same issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5zluG6WkXY)

Comment: On which operating system are you using 2.8.1? Have you considered trying to reproduce this with any of 2.8.2-2.8.7?  When the snapshots are shipping in 5-7 week intervals, it's probably not wise to sit on an old build.

Comment: Using on Windows 10 Enterprise (OS Build 19044.1826). I am unable to download other versions of ArcGIS Pro (as in don't have access to other versions via MyESRI).

Comment: If it is neither the two options you have explored, sounds like a graphic card issue, have you ensured you have the latest drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: @Hornbydd I have an Intel Iris Xe Graphics card and the drivers are saying they are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I did this when I accidentally hid part of the window. Hover near the bottom gray bar on the right side of the popup and you should see some black arrows. Click the left one to unhide the top.

[image]